# Use Rmd files for content pages in blogdown website

Tags: r, blogdown

I am considering switching my website to blogdown. My current set-up only uses .Rmd files with a less-than-ideal blog implementation. It seems like one advantage of blogdown is that it automates the blogging part of the website (posts, lists, dates, etc.) and allows RMarkdown. This is my main motivation to switch. However, the downside, I think, is that I cannot create content pages in RMarkdown (i.e., content > about.Rmd)... it seems this is limited to .md files. I would like to use .Rmd for all the pages so that I can incorporate r code. My question: Is it possible to create .Rmd content pages in blogdown?

EDIT...
Specifically, I created by hand `research.Rmd` in the content folder. I can include a trivial example, such as...

```
`r 2 + 2`
```

and when I run `serve_site()` the r code is not rendered. I can knit the file by hand, but the file does not have the style of the theme I am using and once I again try to serve the site the file is rendered as if it were a .md file.
    ```

EDIT 2...

You can reproduce the behavior I am referring to by doing the following...

1. Create a new blowdown site: `new_site(dir = ".", theme = 'gcushen/hugo-academic')`
2. Create new content: `new_content('test/index.Rmd')`
3. Set draft to `false` and add trivial r code: I used 2 + 2 as shown above.
4. Serve site and go to test/index.html. There is no r code rendered.

Comment: What means "the file does not have the style of the theme I am using" ? Do you speak about syntax highligthing or included css ? The hugo themes takes care of the rendering, it is not rendering exactly like a direct `knit_html`. Considering syntax highlighting, the chosen theme needs to have one included. https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/other-themes.html

Comment: @StatnMap, yes, that is correct. I used the traditional way of knitting as a test to see why it didn't work. I've updated my question to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Please ask one question a time. It will be great if you can remove the second question on child Rmd files, so that we can focus on solving the first one. I'll update my answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Edit 2, you seem to have fallen into a common Hugo trap: `content/test/index.Rmd` does not necessarily generate `test/index.html`. Hugo uses the convention `_index.md` to generate a homepage for a subfolder, and you have to use `content/test/_index.Rmd` in your case. For `content/about.Rmd` or `content/research.Rmd`, they will generate `about/index.html` and `research/index.html` respectively by default.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I have edited my question to include more relevant information.

Comment: That did indeed fix everything. Thank you!